# ngFor data now showing in html

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having issue while passing an array from my **poll-vote.component.ts** to the **poll-vote.component.html** the data is about radio button and i am using ngFor loop with index but this thing is not working for me:

my poll-vote.component.ts code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-poll-vote',
  templateUrl: './poll-vote.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./poll-vote.component.scss'],
})
export class PollVoteComponent implements OnInit {
  pollvoteForm: FormGroup;
  Options: ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday'];
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.pollvoteForm = this.fb.group({
      selection: this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]),
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  submitForm() {
    console.log(this.pollvoteForm.value);
  }
}
```

my poll-vote.component.html code:

```html
<h1>Poll Question title</h1>
<form [formGroup]="pollvoteForm" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
  <div class="form-check" *ngFor="let opt of Options; let i=index">
    <h1>{{opt}}</h1>
    <input
      type="radio"
      class="form-check-input"
      formControlName="selection"
      [value]="i"
    />
    <label class="form-check-label"> {{opt}} </label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary mt-3">Submit Votes</button>
</form>
```

I am new to angular and don't have much knowledge about it

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it, Actually it was just a basic mistake, i had forgot to declare my array
the code is as follow:

```
Options:Array<string>= ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday'];
```